# Reference a particular cell in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a function in VBA that can look at some parameters passed in and then reference a certain column on that row.  To explain a little more, if I try to use the function in cell E1, i want it to say if A1 = 1 then return B1 + C1, Else return B1 + D1.

If i place this function in cell E2, it will do the same thing except with row 2.  I understand how I can do this with a normal excel formula but it will get very messy if i do that.

Can someone please assist with how i might go about writing this?

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: What is so messy about `=B1+IF(A1=1,C1,D1)`?

Comment: that is a simplified version of what i need to do.  there will be a lot more conditions.

Comment: Also, what if you put it in F2? Do you want it to return `(B2=1,C2+D2,C2+E2)`?

Comment: If you have multiple conditions (beyond `A1=1`), then you can use the `AND()` and `OR()` functions to end up with a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value for your conditional.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please post your code.  If you find nested formulae too "messy", I think that trying to do this with VBA is probably not a good idea.  If there truly will be a "lot more conditions", it doesn't seem like you have sufficient grasp of VBA or Excel's object model to implement a user-defined function...

Comment: I used the AND() and it helped.  I will just do it in excel.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked for a VBA solution, but if I understand your question correctly, I strongly recommend using the following formula:

```
=B1+IF(A1=1,C1,D1)
```

Since you're saying that you think a regular formula will be messy, I'm trying to figure out what else you might be trying to do that you haven't said explicitly. If you're saying that you need `A1`'s value to be equal to the row number, for instance, then you can use the following formula instead:

```
=B1+IF(A1=ROW(),C1,D1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function, and use the row/column values of the function's calling cell to define some range objects to work with in your formula.

```
Public Function MyFunction()
Dim r as Long, c As Long
Dim myRange as Range
Dim ret
Dim msg
Set myRange = Application.Caller
r = myRange.Row
c = myRange.Column

msg = "Formula called from: " & myRange.Address

msg = msg & vbCRLF & "The first cell in this row = " & Cells(r, 1).Address

'Alternatively:

msg = msg & vbCRLF &  MsgBox "(Alternatively) " myRange.EntireRow.Cells(1).Address

'## You can also use the OFFSET method to return relative references:

msg = msg & vbCRLF & "Two cells to the left =" & myRange.Offset(0, -2).Address

MsgBox msg, vbInformation

'## Evaluate your example formula:
'   Example does NOT use relative reference and assumes that you
'   Always want to return the function from columns A/B/C/D per
'   your example =IF(A1=1,B1+C1,B1+D1)

If Cells(r, 1) = 1 Then

    ret = Cells(r, 2) + Cells(r, 3)

Else

    ret = Cells(r, 2) + Cells(r, 4)

End If

'return the value to the function:
MyFunction = ret

End Function
```

Comment: You can use Application.Caller to find the calling cell.

Comment: also FYI - you can use "Application.ThisCell" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834969(v=office.15).aspx   Just had to look that up...

Comment: +1. I don't do much with Excel anymore :) @TimWilliams